# 3D scatter plots in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

As a part of project I need to present a 3D scatter plot in a web page based on the 3 columns data from a table from database. Is there a way to draw a 3d scatter plot in ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your third dimension is represented by colour there are many, [Reporting Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) provides all sorts of graph and charting mechanisms. A personal favourite of mine is [JQPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/index.php).

Comment: third dimension is not a color. It is indeed another column which represents some data...Are there any open source third party controls available for 3D scatter plotting..or is there any simple way to do this..